# How to explain this,what happens when we cast signed char to int/hex?

Tags: c

```
signed char num = 220; //DC in hex
printf("%02X\n", num);
printf("%d\n", num);
```

I know that `signed char` can only represent `-128~127`,but why the above outputs:

```
FFFFFFDC
-36
```

What's the reason?

**UPDATE**

My above code is just contrived for my question,that is ,`what happens when we cast signed char to int/hex`

Comment: For the exact reason you just said.

Comment: Wraparound. Undefined behavior. Take your pick. You already explained what's causing the problem. The next step is to fix it: don't assign values to types for which they are out of range.

Comment: I don't think this deserves a down vote, I believe the poster is trying to understand the origin of the "undefined" behavior, not why it occurred. It is fairly obvious why you would not get what you expect when the value is too large, less obvious is why that occurs.

Comment: I thought people whining about downvotes to their *own* posts was bad. But now we've got people whining about downvotes to *other people's posts*. When will the madness end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As our starting point, 220 = DC in hex, and 11011100 in binary.

The first bit is the sign-bit, leaving us with 1011100. Per [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), if we complement it (getting 0100011), and then add one, we get 0100100 -- this is 36.

When it converts the signed char to signed int, it doesn't say "this would be 220 if it's unsigned", it says "this is -36, make it an int of -36", for which the 32-bit two's complement representation is FFFFFFDC, because it must be the negative value for the full size of int (this is called [sign-extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension)):

```
+36 as a 32-bit value: 00000000000000000000000000100100
complement:            11111111111111111111111111011011
add one:               11111111111111111111111111011100
```

Or, in hex, `FFFFFFDC`.

This is why you must be careful with `printf("%x", ch);` (and relatives) -- if you intend to just get a two-digit value, and chars are signed, you may wind up with eight digits instead. Always specify "unsigned char" if you need it to be unsigned.

Comment: is there any reference about the `sign-extension`? Never heard of that terminology.

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, the signed car can have a max value of 127. The reason for the negative number there, however, is due to how the char is stored in memory. All signed integer types save the final bit for sign, with 0/1 denoting positive/negative. The compiler, however, does not check overflow, so when you tried to assign num to 220, it overflowed the value into the sign bit since it could not fit it into the first 7 bits of the char (chars are 1 byte). As a result, when you try to read what is in memory, it sees the sign bit as thrown making the compiler think that instead of seeing a large positive number as you intended, it is instead seeing a small negative value. Hence, the output you see.

**Edit**
Responding to your updated question. All that happens is that the compiler will copy or expand the char to have 4 bytes of memory, interpret the value of the char, and rewrite it in the new int's memory. In you're case, the program at run time would think that the char has a value of -36 instead of 220 because it's interpreting those bits as a signed char before the cast. Then, when it casts, it simply creates an int with value -36.

Answer (score 0):

Your overflow on the assignment, combined with sign extension when you promote it to an int to view it in hex ... see [What's happening in the background of a unsigned char to integer type cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6257807/759749)

Answer (score 0):

Any type smaller that "int" gets converted to "int" when it's passed via "...". This means your negative char got converted to negative int, with FFFs showing up in hex printout.